# Countdown to future day and time titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Hello Guys and working on a soccer prediction app. Am developing the app in titanium environment. But am stuck with a little problem,I'd like to show the remain days and time to the match(date and time are stored in a database),and once the match starts,users should not be able to predict again,and the upcoming match is shown automatically(if the match starts 15:00,the next match show show instead). Have done this on the web using jcountdown. Any suggestion on how to get it done in android using titanium?

Answer (score 0):

This would get you going after a little customization

http://cssgallery.info/create-a-countdown-timer-with-titanium-appcelerator/

Thanks

Comment: Thank You,i'd take a look at it